# What is the difference between array.fill() and array.apply()

Tags: javascript, arrays

### Array.fill()

```
Array(10).fill(0);
```

### Array.Apply()

```
Array.apply(0, new Array(10));
```

Both are doing similarly same. So what is the difference between them and which one is best for performance?

I got a pretty much answer. But

### Update:

**Array.fill()**

```js
console.log(Array(10).fill(undefined));
```

**Array.Apply()**

```js
console.log(Array.apply(undefined, new Array(10)));
```

> Now both are doing similarly same. So what is the difference between them and which one is best for performance?

Comment: What's the point of filling an array with `undefined` anyway? Why not just abstain from defining the elements of the array?

Comment: Seriously, what's so hard about not using blockquote for things that aren't quotes? I'm not going to edit your question again, but c'mon man.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Both are doing similarly same.

No, they aren't. The first fills the array with the value `0`. The second fills it with `undefined`. Note that the `0` you're passing in the second example is completely ignored; the first argument to `Function#apply` sets what `this` is during the call, and [`Array` with multiple arguments](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-array-items) doesn't use `this` at all, so you could pass anything there.

Example:

```js
var first = Array(10).fill(0);
console.log(first);

var second = Array.apply(0, new Array(10));
console.log(second);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

> So what is the difference between them...

See above. :-) Also, see notes below on the follow-up question.

Subjectively: `Array.fill` is clearer (to me). :-)

> ...and which one is best for performance?

It's irrelevant. Use the one that does what you need to do.

---

In a follow-up, you've asked the difference between

```
Array(10).fill(undefined)
```

and

```
Array.apply(undefined, new Array(10))
```

The end result of them is the same: An array with entries whose values are `undefined`. (The entries are really there, e.g. `.hasOwnProperty(0)` will return `true`. As opposed to `new Array(10)` on its own, which creates a sparse array with `length == 10` with no entries in it.)

In terms of performance, it's extremely unlikely it matters. Either is going to be plenty fast enough. Write what's clearest and works in your target environments ([`Array.fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) was added in ES2015, so doesn't exist in older environments, although it can easily be polyfilled). If you're really concerned about the difference in performance, write your real-world code both ways and profile it.

Finally: As far as I know there's no particular limit on the size of the array you can use with `Array.fill`, but `Function#apply` is subject to the maximum number of arguments for a function call and the maximum stack size in the JavaScript platform (which could be large or small; the spec doesn't set requirements). See the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) for more about the limit, but for instance `Array.apply(0, new Array(200000))` fails on V8 (the engine in Chrome, Chromium, and Node.js) with a "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error.

Comment: I'll guess `fill` will still work on humongous arrays, while the size of argument lists for `apply` is limited. Also `fill` is clearly more readable :-)

Comment: @Bergi: Agreed on both points. I'll add a note and link to MDN's comments about `Function#apply`'s limits.

Answer (score 1):

I did a test for that:

```
const calculateApply = function(items){
  console.time('calculateApply');
  Array.apply(undefined, new Array(items));
  console.timeEnd('calculateApply');
} 
const calculateFill = function(items){
  console.time('calculateFill');
  Array(items).fill(undefined);
  console.timeEnd('calculateFill');
} 

const getTime = function(items){
  console.log(`for ${items} items the time of fill is: `)
  calculateFill(items)
  console.log(`for ${items} items the time of apply is:`)
  calculateApply(items)
}

getTime(10)
getTime(100000)
getTime(100000000)
```

and here is the result:

```
for 10 items the time of fill is: 
calculateFill: 0.481ms
for 10 items the time of apply is:
calculateApply: 0.016ms
for 100000 items the time of fill is: 
calculateFill: 2.905ms
for 100000 items the time of apply is:
calculateApply: 1.942ms
for 100000000 items the time of fill is: 
calculateFill: 6157.238ms
for 100000000 items the time of apply is:
/Users/n128852/Projects/pruebas/index.js:3
    Array.apply(0, new Array(items));
          ^

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function.prototype.apply

https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.fill

Here you have the information, like you can read, the apply function prepare params to be executed like a tail recursive method. fill, conversely, is iterative.